# Problem to upload audio file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

Here is my code:

```
if ($_FILES['music']['name'] != '')
{
    $file_name = time() . $_FILES['music']['name'];
    copy($_FILES['music']['tmp_name'], "music/" . $file_name); 
}    
else
{
    $file_name = "";
}
```

I want to upload audio file. the file name is insert into database. but its not insert into folder.

Answer (score 2):

try [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)  instead. You may want to check file size limits too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use **[move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)**, not **copy**

Answer (score 0):

I guess the folder in which you are trying to copy the uploaded file is not the one you expect. Possibly this is what you need:

```
copy($_FILES['music']['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . "/music/" . $file_name);
```

By the way `move_uploaded_file()` works faster and safer than `copy()`.